# Dynamic domain htaccess redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created www domain redirection in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

All works, but I do not want enter manualy domain name every time.
How to change example.com to dynamic domain name?
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```